# Save ArrayList values in Room one by one - Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am saving data with `Room` of `architect component` in my app and I am using from converter but it save like bellow:

[image]

But I need to save values of list one by one in sqlite but save an array.

My entities is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020030/relation-on-entities-android).

And I using bellow converter:

```
public class ContentConverter {
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @TypeConverter
    public List<Content> stringToSomeObjectList(String data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Content>>() {
        }.getType();

        return gson.fromJson(data, listType);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public String someObjectListToString(List<Content> someObjects) {
        return gson.toJson(someObjects);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Are you trying to to save multiple rows in DB where each row will have one `Content` ?

Comment: @ Arka Prava Basu. My problem resolved I am saving data(Array List) in db, one by one.